# How to show different content in an iframe depending on the button you are comming from?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The question title already gives it away basically. What l have are several very similar div-elements and each one of those has a button that should lead to another HTML site on which there is an iframe, and in that iframe an according website to the div element ine is coming from should be displayed.

My problem is mainly that l'm new to js and while showing different content in an iframe when clicking a button isn't a big problem when it is all on the same html, l just couldn't find a way up until now, that would get me from one html to the other while also displaying the corresponding website in the iframe.

Therefore help is much needed and would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need, and edit your question to show us what you have done yourself so far with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.